# I want to make this magento site responsive or mobile friendly

Tags: magento-1.7, rwd, mobile

Please I would like to make this site (http://mushkaperfumes.com/) mobile responsive. When you check using your mobile phone, it doesn't look good. Please who have done this before to help me solve this issue. 
Thank so much..

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use CSS media queries to add style for different browser sizes. It will be better if changed the theme to a responsive theme or used responsive CSS library like Bootstrap or Foundation.